# 'ip rule flush' breaks all connectivity

Tags: iptables, ip

I'm configuring some network stuff, and every time I try something the connection breaks.  Thinking that I must be configuring something incorrectly to break all connections, I did a bit of troubleshooting, to find out that on a fresh boot all networks are working.  If I run the command `ip rule flush` I lose all connectivity until I reboot.

I'm using Kubuntu 12.04 network manager connecting via wireless adapter. Any help appreciated

Comment: could you post the output of 'ip rule show' just after reboot?

Answer (score 7):

I believe this is to be expected.

When you boot there is a rule numbered 32766, as follows:

```
 32766: from all lookup main
```

`main` is the route table normally set up, so unless you have made special preparations you need it. When you enter the `ip rule flush` command it is deleted.

You can add this rule again after flushing by executing:

```
 sudo ip rule add from all lookup main pref 32766
```

I tried this out and, like you, when I did the flush I lost connectivity, and when I re-added it I regained it.

This is the normal set of rules on my 12.04 Ubuntu system:

```
 0: from all lookup local   
 32766: from all lookup main   
 32767: from all lookup default
```

---

Similarly you could also:

`ip rule add from all lookup default pref 32767`

So the script should be something like this:

`ip rule flush`

`ip rule add from all lookup main pref 32766`

`ip rule add from all lookup default pref 32767`

Answer (score 2):

are you sure you are not trying to do the following command instead?

> ip route flush cache

Comment: "ip rule flush" does not take any argument. You are confusing it with "ip route flush cache"

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the correction.